# MYSQL spatial query - Return Polygons that contain points from seperate table

Tags: mysql, spatial-query

I'm new to MYSQL spatial functions. I have successfully created a database with 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE polys (poly POLYGON);
CREATE TABLE points (point POINT);
```

and have filled them with some test data (some points overlapping polygons, some not, some polys contain no points).

What would be the most efficient query to return both the polygons that are overlapped by any point, and a list of the points that are overlapping for each polygon? Is this possible in one query?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at MBROverlaps.

MRBOverlaps(geometry1,geometry2) results in 1/0 if they overlap or not.

Have a look at the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html).

Comment: Thanks. Is this the only way of doing it? It seems each way I can think of putting this into practice, MYSQL will have to iterate over each polygon, and then each point multiplied by each polygon. There may be several thousand polys and several thousand points involved, so im really looking for the most economic way of doing this.

Comment: Well as far as I know MBR functions are the only way to do spatial relationship analysis. To speed it up however you can use a spatial index on them. However the restriction is that you will have to use a MyIsam table. If this has helped feel free to accept the answer and upvote :)

Comment: Thanks, ill look into the spatial index.